# MYSQL assign column name to variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table which has two columns, `business` and `tourist`.

I ask a user to select one of them from dropdown list, then use the result in a `SELECT` statement in MySQL. I assign this column to `$cclass`, then I make this statement `SELECT $cclass FROM flights ...`.

But it always returns `NULL`. Why does it return `NULL` and how do I fix this?

My code:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT $cclass FROM flights WHERE flight_no = '$flightno'");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
{
    $db_seats = $result['$cclass']; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code context, like, where `$cclass` is defined?

Comment: what would the final sql statement look like if you were to echo it out to screen?

Comment: be very careful and make sure you know that $cclass is an actual column name before doing this, otherwise you are at risk of SQL Injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should replace this line:

```
$db_seats = $result['$cclass'];
```

with this:

```
$db_seats = $result[$cclass];
```

string between 2 single quotes doesn't parsed:
[Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I wonder how i didn't notice this ... my error is fixed .. thanks .. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the following:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT".$cclass." FROM flights WHERE flight_no = '$flightno'");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code has a serious security issue, as it is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should be using the [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension instead, and properly filtering your input.

Try something like this:

```
<?php

/* Create the connection. */
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "myDB");
if ($mysql->connect_error)
{
    error_log("Connection failed: " . $mysql->connect_error);
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysql->connect_error);
}

/* Sanitize user input. */
if (!in_array($cclass, array('business', 'tourist')))
{

    error_log("Invalid input: Must be 'business' or 'tourist'");
    die("Invalid input: Must be 'business' or 'tourist'");
}

$statement = $mysql->stmt_init();
$statement->prepare("SELECT $cclass FROM flights WHERE flight_no = ?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $flightno);
if (!$statement->execute())
{
    error_log("Query failed: " . $statement->error);
    die("Query failed: " . $statement->error);
}

if ($statement->num_rows < 1)
{
    echo "No results found.";
}
else
{
    $statement->bind_result($seats);
    while ($statement->fetch())
    {
        echo "Result: $seats";

        // Continue to process the data... You can just use $seats.
    }
}

$mysql->close();
```

However, the reason your original example is failing, is that you're quoting `$cclass`:

```
$db_seats = $result[$cclass];
```

However, please do not ignore the serious security risks noted above.